# How do I enable spell check in Microsoft Communicator 2007?

Tags: ms-office-communicator

I looked in the options but I can't seem to find where I enable spell check. Is there a registry flag I need to set?

If not, does anyone have any third party recommendations? My Google-Fu is not letting me find any relevant results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OC does not have a spell check function.

You can hope someone develops a third-party solution in the future, but I could not find one either, and that seems to be the consensus on other forums, including Microsoft's.

Comment: It's not the answer I was hoping for, but correct none the less.

Comment: @MikeKusold I understand. There are a few of those everyday here. Thank you for accepting the answer despite that.